# Non parametric one sample t-test alternative with a binary variable

Tags: repeated-measures, t-test, nonparametric

I am doing an analysis of items (I1, I2, I3, etc.). The items could be either correctly answered (1) or incorrectly answered (0). Visually, most of the participants answered the items correctly. I want to know whether each of the items was different from 1. I thought to run a Wilcoxon signed rank test for each of the items, but then I realized that I only can do this with scale variables... What can I do instead?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description of the data makes me think this is appropriate to Cochran's $Q$ test:

Data as I understand their description:

```
participant  item1  item2 ... itemp
          1      1      1 ...     1
          2      0      0 ...     1
          .      .      .  .      .
          .      .      .  .      .
          .      .      .  .      .
          n      1      0 ...     0
```

Cochran's $Q$ is a nonparametric analog to the repeated measures ANOVA when data are binary (in the 2 group case it reduces exactly to McNemar's test). It can be followed with pairwise multiple comparisons (using either McNemar's test or Cochran's $Q$), with false discovery rate or familywise error rate multiple comparisons as appropriate. It's implemented [for Stata](http://doyenne.com/stata/cochranq.html) and [variously](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mada/) [for R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RVAideMemoire).

**References**
Cochran, W. G. (1950). The comparison of percentages. *Biometrika*, 37(3/4):256–266.

Mielke, P. W. and Berry, K. J. (1995). Nonasymptotic inferences based on Cochran’s $Q$ test. *Perceptual and Motor Skills*, 81:319–322.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a bit odd as a thing to want to know. For one thing, unless everyone got the answer right, the proportion who got it right *is* different from 1. You might mean "is each variable significantly different from 1"; you could do this with a 1 dimensional chi-square, but it will give infinite $\chi^2$ because it will involve division by 0 (since the "expected" for wrong answer is 0).

It would be more usual to ask if the proportion correct is significantly different from 0.5; you can do this, e.g. in `R` with something like this:

```
correct <- c(5,15)
chisq.test(correct, p = c(0.5,0.5), 
           simulate.p.value = TRUE,
           B = 2000)
```

If 5 people got the question wrong and 15 got it right.

You could substitute some other value for the 0.5, but 0.5 is used because that is what people would get by guessing. So, in the above, we are testing whether people did better than guess.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Peter. Not sure if I was clear enough. What I want to show with this analysis is that they items are simple and for that reason most of the people will solve them. Visually it is quite clear. For example, for the variable1   participant obtained the following: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 and for variable 19, they obtained the following: 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1. So what I want to know is whether the score in these variable are significantly different from 1

Comment: You cannot test that hypothesis. It involves dividing by 0. You can estimate the % correct and get a CI around it.